# Spring ldapTemplate: how to lookup fully qualified DN with configured base DN?

Tags: ldap, spring-ldap

When I do a lookup for a [DN](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Distinguished%20Names) with Springs [ldapTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html), I have to omit the configured base DN.

For example when the base DN is configured as `dc=company,dc=com`, a working lookup would be like

```
ldapTemplate.lookup("ou=whatever,ou=groups")
```

When I pass the fully qualified DN

```
ldapTemplate.lookup("ou=whatever,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com")
```

the lookup fails and complains that the DN `ou=whatever,ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com,dc=company,dc=com` (note the doubled base at the end) does not exist.

**As a consequence, when I do lookups based on returned DNs from previous lookups, I have to remove the base from the end of the DN.**

This is quite annoying and I am almost sure that there is a better way to do this.

**So, how can I do a lookup for a fully qualified DN with a configured base DN?**

I know there is a **query method that takes a base argument**, but this seems to be made for more real queries, not simple lookups.

#### Example use of the accepted answer of @jzheaux

```
LdapName fqdn = ... //fully qualified DN with base DN that is returned from lookup
LdapName baseDn = ((LdapContextSource) ldapTemplate.getContextSource()).getBaseLdapName();
LdapName lookupDn = LdapUtils.removeFirst(fqdn, baseDn);
```

Comment: I've the same problem, so I've opened an issue on the spring ldap repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/issues/new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JavaDoc, this is what `LdapUtils#removeFirst` is for:

```java
/**
 * Remove the supplied path from the beginning the specified
 * <code>Name</code> if the name instance starts with
 * <code>path</code>. Useful for stripping base path suffix from a
 * <code>Name</code>.
**/
```

Alternatively, you can configure your `ContextSource` with no base. Then, all your queries use a fully-qualified name. Or, you can use more than one `ContextSource`; one that has a base configured and another that does not.